# What is f2py used for while building numpy source?

Tags: python, numpy, f2py

When I list all the Fortran files in NumPy's source tree, I get:

```
./doc/source/f2py/scalar.f
./doc/source/f2py/string.f
./doc/source/f2py/calculate.f
./doc/source/f2py/moddata.f90
./doc/source/f2py/array.f
./doc/source/f2py/allocarr.f90
./doc/source/f2py/extcallback.f
./doc/source/f2py/common.f
./doc/source/f2py/ftype.f
./doc/source/f2py/fib3.f
./doc/source/f2py/callback.f
./doc/source/f2py/fib1.f
./doc/f2py/f2python9-final/src/examples/exp1.f
./doc/f2py/simple.f
./doc/f2py/multiarray/foo.f
./doc/f2py/hello.f
./doc/f2py/ex1/bar.f
./doc/f2py/ex1/foobar-smart.f90
./doc/f2py/ex1/foo.f
./doc/f2py/ex1/arr.f
./doc/f2py/ex1/foobar.f90
./numpy/f2py/tests/src/mixed/foo_fixed.f90
./numpy/f2py/tests/src/mixed/foo_free.f90
./numpy/f2py/tests/src/mixed/foo.f
./numpy/f2py/tests/src/size/foo.f90
./numpy/f2py/tests/src/kind/foo.f90
./numpy/f2py/tests/src/assumed_shape/precision.f90
./numpy/f2py/tests/src/assumed_shape/foo_use.f90
./numpy/f2py/tests/src/assumed_shape/.f2py_f2cmap
./numpy/f2py/tests/src/assumed_shape/foo_free.f90
./numpy/f2py/tests/src/assumed_shape/foo_mod.f90
./numpy/f2py/src/test/bar.f
./numpy/f2py/src/test/foo.f
./numpy/f2py/src/test/foo90.f90
./numpy/f2py/src/test/wrap.f
./numpy/distutils/tests/f2py_ext/src/fib1.f
./numpy/distutils/tests/f2py_f90_ext/include/body.f90
./numpy/distutils/tests/f2py_f90_ext/src/foo_free.f90
```

So none other than f2py itself uses Fortran. I looked into the linear algebra modules. For LAPACK, there is a `make_lite.py` file which extracts only the necessary subroutines from a LAPACK source tree, and converts them into C using `f2c`. So when exactly during the creation of NumPy was it convenient to create `f2py`? Am I missing something?

**EDIT**

It turns out a lot of packages inside SciPy use f2py. Running

```
$ find . -iname '*.f*'  | cut -d'/' -f3,4 | uniq
```

gives me the exact directories filled with Fortran files:

```
linalg/src
fftpack/src
odr/odrpack
special/cdflib
special/amos
special/mach
special/specfun
integrate/quadpack
integrate/odepack
integrate/dop
integrate/linpack_lite
integrate/mach
sparse/linalg
interpolate/fitpack
optimize/minpack2
optimize/minpack
optimize/nnls
optimize/cobyla
optimize/lbfgsb
optimize/slsqp
stats/mvndst.f
stats/futil.f
stats/statlib
_build_utils/src
lib/lapack
```

Comment: Notice where those Fortran files are - they are all in either `/doc/` or `/test/` directories. None of them are components of `f2py` itself, which seems to be written in Python and C.

Comment: I have a feeling that `f2py` is actually a requirement for building scipy rather than numpy. Take a look at all of the Fortran files in the scipy source tree - tons of critical stuff including `fftpack`, `odepack`, `arpack`, `fitpack`, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, after a bit of poking around I think I've confirmed a few of my initial suspicions

First:

> So none other than `f2py` itself uses Fortran.

As I mentioned in the comments, all of the Fortran source files the OP is referring to are in `/test/` or `/doc/` directories, and I therefore suspect that they are for testing and documenting `f2py` (and `numpy.distutils`, which uses `f2py`). A glance at a few of the source files seems to confirm this impression. `f2py` itself looks like it's written in Python and C.

> I looked into the linear algebra modules. For LAPACK, there is a make_lite.py file which extracts only the necessary subroutines from a LAPACK source tree, and converts them into C using `f2c`

This seemed strange to me, since I don't actually have `f2c` installed (or `Plex`, which is another library that seems to be required by `make_lite.py`). I decided to stick an extra line in `main()` to show whether `make_lite.py` actually gets used during a normal install:

```
...
def main():

    # let's see if you're actually doing anything
    import subprocess; subprocess.call(['touch', '/tmp/hello_from_make_lite'])
...
```

Sure enough, after installing numpy in a clean virtualenv there is no `hello_from_make_lite` file in my `/tmp/`, indicating that `make_lite.main()` never executed. Take a look at `numpy/linalg/lapack_lite/README`:

> The `numpy/linalg/blas_lite.c`, `numpy/linalg/dlapack_lite.c`, and
>   `numpy/linalg/zlapack_lite.c` are `f2c`'d versions of the LAPACK routines
>   required by the `LinearAlgebra` module, and wrapped by the `lapack_lite`
>   module. The scripts in this directory can be used to create these files
>   automatically from a directory of LAPACK source files.

So numpy is already distributed with these `f2c`'d C source files - there's no need to use `make_lite.py` unless you're a dev wanting to update these functions from a new version of the LAPACK library.

> So when exactly during the creation of NumPy was it convenient to create `f2py`?

As far as I can tell, `f2py` doesn't get used *at all* during a normal numpy install. Again, I stuck an extra line in `f2py2e.main()`:

```
...
def main():
    import subprocess; subprocess.call(['touch', '/tmp/hello_from_f2py2e'])
...
```

And again, `/tmp/hello_from_f2py2e` doesn't exist after a normal install of numpy.

So what is `f2py` actually used for? Check out the scipy source tree, and from its root call

```
$ find . -iname *.f*
```

You'll see loads and loads of important-looking Fortran files, including `fftpack`, `odepack`, `arpack`, `fitpack`, etc. I suspect that `f2py` is mainly required to wrap the Fortran extensions for scipy rather than numpy.

I might be wrong, though - perhaps one of the numpy or scipy devs will set me straight.

### Update

Actually, I think `f2py` is not actually required during a normal installation of scipy either! If you take a look in the source directory for one of the Fortran modules, e.g. [`fftpack`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/tree/master/scipy/fftpack), you'll see that it already contains `.pyf` files, which would normally be automatically generated by `f2py` and define the interfaces for the Fortran functions (see [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/c-info.python-as-glue.html#improving-the-basic-interface)).

I think the deal is that `f2py` was used to initially generate the `.pyf` wrappers for the Fortran functions, but these `.pyf` files are distributed along with the rest of the source tree so that it's unnecessary to run `f2py` again during the normal build process.

Comment: A modified version of f2c is present under linalg/lapack_lite

Comment: Looking at scipy source, I see many packages with Fortran files.

Comment: I'm beginning to think f2py is dead code. The documentation pages on the web all cyclically reference one another, if not referencing a dead link, and it appears, with what few coherent f2py pages that exists, that the code hasn't been touched in 5 years, if not longer.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but the purpose of f2py is to allow users of numpy to wrap their own arbitrary Fortran routines and call them from within Python.  I've used it to call some custom Kalman filter code that I had.  Calling the Fortran version was significantly faster than the same algorithm translated into numpy, probably due to a bunch of array slicing.  However, as numba has gotten better, I've leaned more towards decorating the numpy code with @njit instead.